# Directory contents (project files) not showing up when trying to commit / push / update repo

Tags: git, macos, terminal

I'm attempting to push the latest contents to my remote repo. It appears when I look from the browser the contents in directory SuperheroShawn aren't shown when I did my last commit, and I assume they should appear in the git status as well? All I see is the actual folder that is shown via the browser with no contents (See Image Below):

[image: Project files are not showing up in directory SuperheroShawn]

This is what appears in terminal when I do git status (I assume the project files should appear here as well that are in the Week1and2 folder and not just the directory path?):

[image: What appears when I type git status, I assume project files should be listed here as well if all was working properly?]

**Actual folder contents of SuperheroShawn that I want to be able to track/commit :**
[image: Actual contents of SuperheroShawn that I want to be able to track/commit on]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, and why it's not detecting these project files in SuperheroShawn so that I can start pushing out commits?

**I tried 'git commit -a' and get this:**
[image]

Comment: have you tried "git commit -a" like the message says?

Comment: Yes and I get the following response via terminal (updated question) although the project files are clearly in directory but not showing up when changes are done, or even on the initial commit they weren't added in it appears (as  see in very first screen shot above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git has a staging area where you select new files and file modifications to be tracked in the repo. To get your new files to appear in the git repository, you need to specifically add them to be tracked.

It's not enough to do `git commit -a`, because that only stages modifications, it doesn't stage new files.

---

To stage all files in the current directory for addition to the repo, run the following:

```
git add .
```

If you run `git status` afterwards, you will see all the files have been added to be tracked. Then just `git commit` normally and all your files will be added to the repo.

For more information about how staging works in git, please read [this page of the git-scm docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics).

Comment: Thanks, you're a lifesaver.